# Something is wrong with my CSS ID: it doesn't work

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, web

**# I can't see what is wrong with this, I have an HTML file and a CSS file**

```css
body {
  font-size: 16px;
  color: black;
  background-color: #61122f;
  font-family: 'Oxygen', sans-serif;
}

#header-nav {
  background-color: #f6b319;
  border-radius: 0;
  border: 0;
}

#logo-img {
  background: url("pngtree-coffee-time-png-image_3626459.jpg")
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-4bw+/aepP/YC94hEpVNVgiZdgIC5+VKNBQNGCHeKRQN+PtmoHDEXuppvnDJzQIu9" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <!--fonts-->
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Oxygen:wght@300;400;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <nav id="header-nav" class="navbar navbar-expand-lg bg-body-tertiary">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <a href="index.html" class="pull-left visible-md visible-lg">
            <div id="logo-img"></div>
          </a>

        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </header>
</body>

</html>
```

My problem is the id="header-nav" under the header tag doesn't work, and so does the id="logo-img" :(

I'm following an online lesson and doing exactly the same but my code is not applied. I have checked it on validation and it said nothing wrong. Please someone tell me what's wrong with this?

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean? Be SPECIFIC.

Comment: I want to set the background color of that nav id to orange but it stays white as the default

Comment: You can [edit] your question and click the [<>] looking icon to produce an actual live sample right here in your question. Please do that and provide a [mre] that demonstrates that behavior.

Comment: Use your browser devtools inspect facility to see exactly what/where is applying the CSS to those elements. It’s probably bootstrap

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the Bootstrap you have linked is higher specificity than your own CSS. Take a look [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) for a deeper dive on specificity. I was able to use your property by adding `!important` to the background color option.

Edit: It's more of a cascade issue instead, due to the classes overriding each other with !important.

```css
body {
  font-size: 16px;
  color: black;
  background-color: #61122f;
  font-family: 'Oxygen', sans-serif;
}

#header-nav {
  background-color: #f6b319 !important;
  border-radius: 0;
  border: 0;
}

#logo-img {
  background: url("pngtree-coffee-time-png-image_3626459.jpg");
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-4bw+/aepP/YC94hEpVNVgiZdgIC5+VKNBQNGCHeKRQN+PtmoHDEXuppvnDJzQIu9" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <!--fonts-->
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Oxygen:wght@300;400;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <nav id="header-nav" class="navbar navbar-expand-lg bg-body-tertiary">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <a href="index.html" class="pull-left visible-md visible-lg">
            <div id="logo-img"></div>
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </header>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: This is something different from specificity. An `id` is less specific than a `class`, so Bootstrap shouldn't be overriding this. It has to be something else. `!important` does fix it, but specificity isn't the real issue here.

Comment: @davidleininger I just looked, the `.bg-body-tertiary` class has !important on it's `background-color` property, so it is technically specificity.

Comment: I stand corrected, though two `!important` values is more of a cascade issue than a specificity issue: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dS123IXPcJ0

Answer (score -1):

While I typically try to stay away from using `!important` unless you have to, you can add that to your background color and it will override the bootstrap color.

It seems like there is some kind of layering/specificity issue. You're using an `id` which has a specificity value of `1,0,0` and Bootstrap is using a `class` which has a value of `0,1,0`. So this is more than just a specificity issue as your `id` is a high specificity and should override their `class`.

Learn more about Specificity and how it is [calculated](https://polypane.app/css-specificity-calculator/) on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity).

---

**Update:** It looks like the issue is because Bootstrap is using `!important` on their class. Learn about how `!important` works and is rendered here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dS123IXPcJ0. This is a cascade issue where two different `!important` properties.

```css
body {
  font-size: 16px;
  color: black;
  background-color: #61122f;
  font-family: 'Oxygen', sans-serif;
}

#header-nav {
  background-color: #f6b319 !important;
  border-radius: 0;
  border: 0;
}

#logo-img {
  background: url("pngtree-coffee-time-png-image_3626459.jpg")
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-4bw+/aepP/YC94hEpVNVgiZdgIC5+VKNBQNGCHeKRQN+PtmoHDEXuppvnDJzQIu9" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <!--fonts-->
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Oxygen:wght@300;400;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <nav id="header-nav" class="navbar navbar-expand-lg bg-body-tertiary">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <a href="index.html" class="pull-left visible-md visible-lg">
            <div id="logo-img"></div>
          </a>

        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </header>
</body>

</html>
```